# OSX "loginwindow" PAM config file?

Tags: osx-lion, osx-snow-leopard, pam

I'm back again with the never ending saga of writing a PAM module for OSX.  I have the module written.  It works when using ssh or starting a new terminal window or su.  What I really, really, really want is just ssh and the loginwindow.

My PAM module works in "session" mode.  It either returns PAM_SUCCESS or PAM_IGNORE.  Again, it works with other PAM aware systems like ssh and su.  I really want to hook into the loginwindow.  Any idea how to do this with OSX and openPAM?

I have seen a couple potential answers that suggest using the "pam.d/authenticate" file.  This has not worked yet.  Setting my session line in there seems to cause the system's connection to Active Directory to fail.

I have also tried creating a "pam.d/loginwindow" file just in case there was a provision for it -- no joy.

ideas?

Comment: Bother, at least this post: [link](http://www.thegeekispeak.com/archives/205 claims it is impossible).

Comment: There seems to be a way described in this post on getting YubiKeys working with OSX.https://github.com/Yubico/yubico-pam/wiki/ChallengeResponse-%28on-Mac-OS-X%29

Comment: Interesting.  I am only doing "session" work, not "auth" but this does give me another idea.  Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I know this is too late. I have been working out with PAM modules lately. For adding the module to the login window, you need to add your .so file to the authorisation configuration file in mac located in /etc/pam.d/authorisation. You should place your .so file under /usr/lib/pam/ directory.

Also before the PAM module if you want to fiddle around with the Mac Login Window view, you need to do it using the SFAuthorizationPluginView Class. There is a sample plugin code at Apple developer. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/NameAndPassword/Introduction/Intro.html

There is also some documentation by Apple over Login processes. You can take reference [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2228/_index.html)!

Hope that helps. Cheers!!

Comment: Hi, Did you managed to customize the login window and integrate it with PAM? We have a PAM plugin that works with SSH connection but failed to customize the login window. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, to answer your question, yes I was able to. I think you are trying to do in ssh, but for login window of mac you need to do in the login config file under /etc/pam.d . Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Tushar. Our PAM plugin works fine on Mac with SSH connection, what we expect is on the login window the user will be prompted with the second factor authentication based on our PAM plugin. To achieve this, if I understand you right, we need to wrote a `SFAuthorizationPluginView ` plugin to customize the login window and hook it up with our PAM plugin? Is there any valid guid/tutorial about how to achieve this? I found `NameAndPassword` and `NullAuthPlugin` both out of date. Or can we just modify `/etc/pam.d/authorization` and the prompt will be enabled automatically? Thank you!

Comment: Okay. It has been a while for me I worked on it. But I can show you the way. First, create the 'NameAndPassword' plugin and set the data in call `[self callbacks]->SetContextValue([self engineRef], kAuthorizationEnvironmentPassword, 1, &userPassValue)` . Now you can use the value in PAM plugin and do the processing you want to. One more thing, you would have to  remove PAM converse functions. I think you are not able to integrate it with this reason. :)

Comment: Thanks Tushar. Looks like we do not have a way to integrate SFAuthorizationPluginView with PAM directly.

Comment: Umm. Sorry things didn't work out for you. I can help you out if you can explain me what exactly you want to do over email. It is possible that if we modify approach then we can work it out.

Comment: Great! I really appreciate your help Tushar. I actually have a opening question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34007557/integrate-pam-plugin-with-mac with all the details about what I am trying to do. Maybe you can kindly take a look and give me some hints there. Thanks!