# Unlock a Mac using public API?

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-yosemite, appkit

I have seen an app on the App Store which can unlock a mac using touch id, I have been trying to find a public API for a Mac app that could achieve this. How would I go about performing the unlock in a mac App written in objective c?

Any links to documentation would be very useful.

(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OuDa0pzmMP0) this is a demo of the App in question.

Comment: This question is a little too broad to properly answer, as there's certainly a number of components in play here.  TouchID on the iPhone, some combination of [SFAuthorizationPluginView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/SFAuthorizationPluginView_Class/index.html), a [PAM module](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/pam.3.html) and who knows what else.  [Here is a potentially useful related question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842945/osx-loginwindow-pam-config-file).

Comment: All i want to do is write an app for the mac that can unlock the Mac, the rest is outside the domain of my question. Literally just the mechanisms that would allow an OS X app to unlock the screen. I have sniffed around the terminal commands for CGSession -switchUserId but this does not seem to fit the purpose i am going for.